# Busybox `uname -r` shows wrong kernel version

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, busybox

My kernel is 3.2.27 and `/lib/modules/` contains **3.2.27 +** folder. But when I am using

```
/# uname -r
3.1.9+
```

It's showing a strange output. My problem is that for modprobe depends on uname when I put

```
/# modprobe somemodule
modprobe: chdir(3.1.9+): No such file or directory
```

It finding the modules in a wrong path. I have cross compiled the kernel with `gcc` version 4.5.2. Can anyone tell me why this strange problem happens?

Thank you

Comment: `uname` uses the `uname()` system call, so fetch this info directly from the running kernel. Alternatively, cat `/proc/version`, which should yield the same info.

Comment: `cat /proc/version` also showing `3.1.9+`

Comment: I have cross compiled the kernel with `gcc` version 4.5.2

Comment: Then somewhere within your compilation you are setting the kernel version to 3.1.9+

Comment: You're clearly running kernel 3.1.9. Are you sure you booted the kernel you intended?

Comment: @Gilles yes I am booting the correct `Image` file,actually I am using `raspberry pi`. But is there any option in kernel compilation to set up kernel version externally??

Comment: @fpmurphy is it possible to set kernel version externally?